# Veeam automation backup script in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a simple script to monitor the backup process for veeam, script accept only drives that should be on current days (to avoid override of data), monitor 2 backup jobs. Definitely could be done better, please suggest something to improve performance or tip with good practices.

```
    #Mon  Z1Z2E34C
#Teu  WD-WCC5D2TSV3P1
#We   WD-WCC132VE1XAN
#Thu  WD-WCC4E1615112
#week WD-WCC131092470
$disks = @('Z1Z2E34C', 'WD-WCC5D2TSV3P1', 'WD-WCC132VE1XAN', 'WD-WCC4E1615112', 'weekly')
$day = @("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendsday", "Thursday", "Weekly")
$jobname = "Copy Job - Backup_Job_RITZ-CFS01 Removable"
$jobname2 = "Copy Job - Data Stores - Daily - Removable"
$job = get-vbrjob -name $jobname
$job2 = get-vbrjob -name $jobname2
function Progress {
    #cls
    Do {
        $JobStatus1 = ($job.GetLastState())
        $JobStatus2 = ($job2.GetLastState())
        Write-Host 'waiting for Veem to start backup'
        Start-Sleep 4
        Clear-Host
    } Until($JobStatus1 -eq 'Starting' -or $JobStatus1 -eq 'Working')
    Do {
        $i = $job.FindLastSession().BaseProgress
        $JobStatus1 = ($job.GetLastState())
        $text = "Running Job:  $job Status: $JobStatus1"
        Write-Progress -Activity $text -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i -Id 1
        $i2 = $job2.FindLastSession().BaseProgress
        $JobStatus2 = ($job2.GetLastState())
        $text2 = "Running Job:  $job2 Status: $JobStatus2"
        Write-Progress -Activity $text2 -Status "$i2% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i2 -Id 2
    }Until (($i -eq 100 -and $JobStatus1 -eq "Idle") -and ($i2 -eq 100 -and $JobStatus2 -eq "Idle"))
}
function FormatDisk {
    $x = Get-Disk | Where-Object SerialNumber -match $currentDisk | Select-Object Number -ExpandProperty Number
    Initialize-Disk -Number $x
    Clear-Disk -Number $x -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
    Initialize-Disk -Number $x
    New-Partition –DiskNumber $x –UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter E
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter E -FileSystem NTFS -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -NewFileSystemLabel $timestamp
    New-Item -Path "E:\" -Name "VeeamExtract" -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path "E:\" -Name "VeeamBackups" -ItemType "directory"
    cmd /c "Net Share RemovableDrive=E:\ /grant:Everyone,Full"
    Copy-Item "C:\Program Files\Veeam\Backup and Replication\Backup\Extract.exe" -Destination "E:\VeeamExtract"
    Copy-Item "C:\Program Files\Veeam\Backup and Replication\Backup\Veeam.Backup.Extractor.exe" -Destination "E:\VeeamExtract"
}
While ($true) {
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        $currentDisk = $disk
        $currentDay = $day.item($disks.IndexOf($disk))
        if ( $disks.IndexOf($disk) -eq $disks.Count - 1) {
            $nextDisk = $disks[0]
            $nextDay = $day[0]
        }
        else {
            $nextDisk = $disks.Item($disks.IndexOf($disk) + 1)
            $nextDay = $day.Item($disks.IndexOf($disk) + 1)
        }
        Do {
            $disksUID = @(Get-Disk | Select-Object SerialNumber)
            $timestamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y"
            Clear-Host
            Write-Host 'waiting for disk ' $currentDisk '('$currentDay')'
            Start-Sleep 5
        } Until (($disksUID -match $disk) -or ($disk -eq "weekly"))
        #cls
        Write-Host 'Current disk ID: '$currentDisk '('$currentDay')'
        Write-Host 'next disk ID: '$nextDisk '('$nextDay')'
        FormatDisk
        Progress
        cls
        Write-Host $x
        Set-Disk -Number $x -IsOffline $True
    }
}
```